Serializing pydantic enums
Just getting started with pydantic. I have this example code:
class FinishReason(Enum):
    stop = 'stop'

class Choice(BaseModel):
    finish_reason: FinishReason = Field(...)

But I cannot serialize this:
json.dumps(Choice(finish_reason=FinishReason.stop).dict())
*** TypeError: Object of type FinishReason is not JSON serializable

I get the object not the value:
(Pdb) Choice(finish_reason=FinishReason.stop)
Choice(finish_reason=<FinishReason.stop: 'stop'>)

Also tried it with .value, same result.
What am I missing here?

Actually it's as simple as adding this to any model that uses an enum model:
class Config:
    use_enum_values = True

